# Formatting not applied to a singular point in boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, formatting, boxplot

All the points displayed in my figure EXCEPT ONE are formatted correctly in terms of color, size, and shape. I can't figure out why that one point (see image) is different than the rest. I have looked at the input data and there's nothing out of the ordinary and I've used the same block of code to make similar figures without this happening. Any Suggestions?

Here's the code:

```
infil = ggplot(soil21, aes(x=Treatment, y=infil, col=Treatment)) + 
  geom_boxplot(fill='#f3f3f3', color="black")+
  geom_jitter(shape=19, size=1.75, position=position_jitter(0.2)) + 
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#0677B6", "#6AC7FA")) +
  ggtitle("Infil") + ylab("Y axis") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 17)) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom") +
  theme(legend.title=element_blank())
infil
```

[image: 1]

Comment: This is an outlier added by geom_boxplot. You could remove the outliers by adding e.g. `geom_boxplot(..., outlier.shape = NA)`.

Comment: Hi @Spencer, could you please share your data using `dput(soil21)`? So we can help you better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, this solved it:

> This is an outlier added by geom_boxplot. You could remove the outliers by adding e.g. `geom_boxplot(..., outlier.shape = NA)` - [stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12993861/stefan)